# what's the best way to re-index just the models that changed during solr downtime?

Tags: lucene, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

if I have millions of User records with some text fields getting indexed to solr on create and on update, how do I go back and re-index the few records that never made it to solr?

i.e. what if solr goes down for a few minutes during the day and about 300 records out of millions never got indexed.

I don't want to re-index millions of records, just the 300.

Comment: found a great gem: https://github.com/bdurand/sunspot_index_queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good way to manage this would be to just insert the record IDs into a queue table on create  and update, and then have a process that runs later to index the records.  That way if Solr goes down, you don't have to worry about which records weren't processed, they'll just continue sitting in the queue until processed.  The advantage of this is that your database doesn't have to wait for the solr update to complete before completing the transaction.  The downside is that Solr isn't going perfectly in sync with what's in the database. You can adjust how often the queue reading program runs to accommodate your needs for that.

Comment: excellent points.  why am I letting this mission critical operation occur in realtime.  we have other queues, this should also be a queue.  thanks.

Comment: +1 for this. Queueing is absolutely the way to go with Solr updates. Another approach would be to save some kind of indexed_at timestamp on your records when they have been successfully indexed, and use that to find batches that need to be updated.